# Using a macro in call to malloc

Tags: c, macros, malloc

I'm just a bit stuck as to why this doesn't work. Am I missing something obvious? This is what I am trying to do:

```
#define LENGTH 4;
new->array = malloc(sizeof(int)*LENGTH);
```

I'm using Xcode and getting errors for 'expected ")"' at the start of LENGTH and 'expected expression' at the end of LENGTH.

But this is ok:

```
int size = sizeof(int)*LENGTH;
new->array = malloc(size);
```

What is the reason why I cannot do the first one?

Comment: remove `;` at the end of define, and its better to enclose 4 into braces, like `(4)`

Comment: And now it's obvious! Now I feel silly. Thank you. I would mark as correct if it wasn't a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LENGTH` gets replaced by `4;`, so you get

```
new->array = malloc(sizeof(int)*4;);
```

That is syntactically invalid. Remove the trailing `;` from the define:

```
#define LENGTH 4
```

Also note this has nothing to do with `malloc`.